# Native Quarkus Application with dynamic groovy execution

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-native

Currently I have a microservice written in kotlin using vertx framework.

I like to rewrite this service with quarkus and build a native executable.

The service currently uses the class GroovyShell to dynamically execute groovy scripts:

```
val groovyShell = GroovyShell(sharedData)
val scriptContent = loadScript(..)
groovyShell.parse(scriptContent).run()
```

Is this possible with a quarkus native executable or is this "dynamic" part not possible with graalvm?